# How to use creative sdk with retrolambda plugin with java 1.7 version

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk, retrolambda

I am trying to use creative sdk for image editing in my application.

I have done the setup and its working fine. Now my question is I have some limitation in development environment that I have to use java 1.7. When I set java version for my project to 1.7 I am not able run the application. I am getting the error ***When running gradle with java 5, 6 or 7, you must set the path to jdk8, either with property retrolambda.jdk or environment variable JAVA8_HOME***

I found some solutions [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169381)  but its not solved my issue. Can anybody help me to solve this issue.

In summary my question is **I just need to setup the creative sdk library with java 1.7**.

Answer (score 0):

The Creative SDK currently requires that you use Java 8 and Retrolambda.

The setup for this is detailed in the [Getting Started guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html) and illustrated in these [sample apps on GitHub](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples).